# CSS why do you need pseudo elements with empty string

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

In this [example](https://codepen.io/shayhowe/pen/jelsr), why does `container` need to have the pseudo-element `after` and `before` with `content: ''` and `display: table` to show the gray background? Shouldn't `container` automatically expand to fit both of its children and then fill out the negative space with the gray background without the pseudo-elements already?

Answer (score -1):

This is called a 'clearfix', when a container has all of his the childs floating, you have to use a clearfix on it.
I put a black background in the container:

**With clearfix:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvoEjx

**Without clearfix:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvxgRe

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

```
.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, `display: flow-root` is now an option in some browsers, for which the explanation of how it differs from clearfix is quite technical.

Comment: clear:fix doesn't allow elements to be floating above it, but in this situation how does it affect whether the container element get a background or not?

Comment: Also for that example, why do you need it in the `before`? Don't you just need it for the `after`?

Comment: The element get a background in any case, but without clearfix, The container cant get The height of The content, in other words, we cant see The background @stackjlei

Comment: You dont need to know how it works, but what it does

Comment: You might as well not bother answering the question in that case.

Comment: Omg, just google clearfix